# I just started to run spring boot application and the browser is showing this error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

Please explain me what is wrong here, why am I getting this type of error?
error message is : Unable to infer base url. This is common when using dynamic servlet registration or when the API is behind an API Gateway. The base url is the root of where all the swagger resources are served. For e.g. if the api is available at http://example.org/api/v2/api-docs then the base url is http://example.org/api/. Please enter the location manually:

I am new to asking questions in stack overflow , please suggest me on how to structure this question properly
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXxnS.png

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add this annotation, please add this to main class.

```
@EnableSwagger2
```

Comment: oh yes! I forgot about it , Thank you so much